# How to reorder columns of hunderds of tab deliminated file in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have large scale tab-delimited files (a couple of hundreds), and but the order of the columns is different across the different files( the same columns, but different locations). Hence, I need to reorder all the columns in all the files and write it back in tab-deliminated format.
I would like to write a shell script that takes a specified order of columns and reorder all the columns in all the files and write it back. Can someone help me with it?

Here is how the header of my files looks like:
file1)

```
sLS72   chrX
A   B   E   C   F   H
2   1   4   5   7   8
0   0   0   0   0   0
```

and the header of my second file:

```
S721    chrX
A   E   B   F   H   C
12  11  2   3   4   1
0   0   0   0   0   0
```

here is the order of the columns that I want to achieve:

```
Order=[A ,B ,C ,E,F,H]
```

and here is the expected outputs for each file based on this ordering:

```
  sLS72 chrX
    A   B   C   E   F   H
    2   1   5   4   7   8
    0   0   0   0   0   0
```

file 2:

```
S721    chrX
A   B   C   E   F   H
12  2   1   11  3   4
0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I was trying to use awk:

```
awk -F'\t' '{s2=$A; $3=$B; $4=$C; $5=$E; $1=s}1' OFS='\t' in file
```

but the point is the, first, the order of columns are different in different files, and second, the names of the columns start from the second line of the file. In order words, first line is the header, I don't want to change it, but the second line is the colnames of the columns, so I want to order all files based on that. it's kind of tricky

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to use cut, but was not sucessfull

Comment: Is your header two lines?

Comment: First line is the header, I don't want to change it, but second line is the colnames of the columns, so I want to order all files based on that.

Comment: You want to output `A   E   B   F   H   C` in order `A,B,C,D,E,F`? What about the unmatching fields?

Comment: The second line is the same with all files, only the order are different

Comment: I can see that, but the expected order has different letters (header names) as the data fields.

Comment: That's right. We keep the header unchanged, but we want to reorder the file based on colnames in the second line

Comment: Please post the expected output.

Comment: @JamesBrown, I've updated it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v order="A B C E F H" '
    BEGIN  {n=split(order,ho)} 
    FNR==1 {print; next} 
    FNR==2 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) hn[$i]=i} 
           {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s",$hn[ho[i]] (i==n?ORS:OFS)}' file1 > tmp && mv tmp file1

sLS72   chrX
A B C E F H
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

if working on multiple files at the same time, change it to

```
$ awk -v ...
        {... printf "%s",$hn[ho[i]] (i==n?ORS:OFS) > (FILENAME"_reordered") }' dir/files*
```

and do a mass rename afterwards.  Alternative is run the original script if a loop for each file.

Comment: This gives the following error when there is more than one file needed to be reordered usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
(base) 30-109-227:test azim$ ./Reorder_Marks.sh

Comment: I'm working with hundreds of files, so it's not easy to list all them life file1, file2, ... in the command. Can you edit your code? This will be helpful for many people

Comment: it doesn't work on multiple fines. I have a directory with the hunders of files that need to be reorderd. Thanks for the hlep